# whats the difference between # include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp" and # include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

Tags: c++, opencv, header, include

Some programs have the first one, while others have the second one. What is the difference between the two, and when do we use them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a legitimate question in my opinion. Quote from the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html):

> Headers layout
>
> In 2.4 all headers are located in corresponding module subfolder
>   (opencv2/module/module.hpp), in 3.0 there are top-level module
>   headers containing the most of the module functionality:
>   opencv2/module.hpp and all C-style API definitions have been moved
>   to separate headers (for example opencv2/core/core_c.h).

If you are using OpenCV 3, you can use both syntax but it is preferable to use the latter one (`opencv2/highgui.hpp`).

Use the first one (`opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp`) if you are using OpenCV 2.4 or want your program to be backward compatible with OpenCV 2.4.

Comment: Great answer. It's the same problem with the opencv2/core.hpp and the opencv2/core/core.hpp